# Second Scraper - If Statement

Tags: html, python-3.x, if-statement, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on my second Python scraper and keep running into the same problem.  I would like to scrape the website shown in the code below.  I would like to be ability to input parcel numbers and see if their Property Use Code matches.  However, I am not sure if my scraper if finding the correct row in the table. Also, not sure how to use the if statement if the use code is not the 3730.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
parcel = input("Parcel Number: ")
web = "https://mcassessor.maricopa.gov/mcs.php?q="
web_page = web+parcel
web_header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh;IntelMacOSX10_13_2)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/63.0.3239.132Safari/537.36'}
response=requests.get(web_page,headers=web_header,timeout=100)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
table=soup.find("td", class_="Property Use Code" )
first_row=table.find_all("td")[1]
if first_row is '3730':
    print (parcel)
else:
   print ('N/A')
```

Comment: What's your question? What output are you getting and how does it differ from what you expected? Give an example of what's in the `parcel` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no td with class "Property Use Code" in the html you're looking at - that is the *text* of a td. If you want to find that row, you can use

```
td = soup.find('td', text="Property Use Code")
```

and then, to get the next td in that row, you can use:

```
otherTd = td.find_next_sibling()
```

or, of you want them all:

```
otherTds = td.find_next_siblings()
```

It's not clear to me what you want to do with the values of these tds, but you'll want to use the `text` attribute to access them: your `first_row is '3730'` will always be False, because `first_row` is a `bs4.element.Tag` object here and `'3730'` is a `str`. You can, however, get useful information from `otherTd.text == '3730'`.